# Golang: RabbitMQ receiver + concurrent map + http server

Tags: go, rabbitmq

**TL;DR**

What can I do to make two services (rabbitMQ consumer + HTTP server) share the same [map](https://github.com/orcaman/concurrent-map)?

**More info**

I'm new to Golang. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

I have a RabbitMQ consumer receiving some json-format messages and store them into a  [concurrent map](https://github.com/orcaman/concurrent-map). On the other hand, I need an HTTP server that sends data from the concurrent map whenever a GET request arrives.

I kinda know that I need the`"net/http"` package for the HTTP server and the rabbitMQ client package.

However, I'm not sure how these two services can share the same map. Could anyone please offer some idea? Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

One possible solution I can think of is to replace the concurrent map with Redis. So the running consumer will send the data to Redis server whenever a message arrives and then the http server will serve GET request from the data in Redis. But is there a better way to achieve my goal without adding this extra layer (Redis)?

Comment: RabbitMQ is a durable place for messages to live while being processed.  Your concurrent map, not so much.  Redis, not so much.  Pull the messages from rabbitmq as they're requested.

Comment: @DanielFarrell Thanks for the comment but in fact, I need to do some calculation based on the historical messages I received from RabbitMQ -- for example, I need to return the top 5 messages based on some attributes.

Comment: Sounds like what you actually want is the ability to analyze traffic after the fact.  You wouldn't want to make that part of your message delivery process.  Instead, you want to record  the messages you received - or the relevant parts - in something like elasticsearch and then you can analyze them later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your two "services" live inside the same Go program, dependency injection. You can define a type that wraps your map (or provides equivalent functionality), instantiate it when your application starts, and inject it into both the HTTP handler and the MQ consumer.

The following code is meant to illustrate the concept:

```
package mymap

// imports

type MyMap struct {
   // fields
}
```

```
package main

// imports

func main() {
   ...

   // instantiate the shared map object
   sharedMap := &MyMap{ /* init fields as appropriate */ }

   mqconsumer := &mqpkg.Consumer{
       SharedMap: sharedMap // inject the map obj into the mq consumer
       // ...
   }
   // start the mq consumer

   // inject the map obj into the http handler
   http.HandleFunc("/foo", handlerWithMap(sharedMap))

   log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}


func handlerWithMap(mymap *mymap.MyMap) http.HandlerFunc {
   return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
       // here the http handler is able to access the shared map object
   }
}
```

With that said, unless your application has particular requirements, I would recommend to implement your own synchronized map. This isn't too difficult to accomplish with the `sync` package. The disadvantage of using third-party libraries is that you lose type safety, because their signatures must be designed to accept and return `interface{}`'s.

Comment: https://github.com/farrellit/stackoverflow/blob/main/66719964/server/server.go#L14  is a complete but simple example of a concurrent map backing an http server if you'd like to see how a `sync.RWMutex` can be used to guard concurrent access to a map.